# json iOS parsing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to parse the following json into my iOS code.

```
{
    "test": [
        {
            "id": "21",
            "lat": "53.343377977116916",
            "long": "-6.2587738037109375",
            "address": "R138, Dublin, Ireland",
            "name": "td56",
            "distance": "0.5246239738790947"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "lat": "53.343377977116916",
            "long": "-6.245641708374023",
            "address": "68-130 Pearse Street, Dublin, Ireland",
            "name": "test1",
            "distance": "0.632357483022306"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to view the full json in my logs with the following code:

```
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URLHERE"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
NSDictionary *test = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"test"];
NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);
```

if I change data dictionary to test in the log, I can display after the test root in my json , but if I try setup arrays to view, let's say the ID, the entire app will crash.

Could someone direct me in the right way to, let's say, display all the names in the `NSLog`? Each method I've tried has resulted in the application crashing.

Comment: Can you post the crash log or stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test is an array:

```
NSArray *test = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"test"];
NSLog(@"test =%@", test);

for(NSDictionary *coordinates in test){
   NSLog(@"id  = %@", coordinates[@"id"]);
   NSLog(@"lat  = %@", coordinates[@"lat"]);
   NSLog(@"long  = %@", coordinates[@"long"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, what if I want to get the names and only log them? How would I go about that? I have managed to get into the test root already but I cannot get the names or anything else in the log without it crashing

Comment: I keep getting expected method to read directory on object of type.... and it fails to build.

Comment: I'm getting expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'
        NSLog(@"id  = %@", test[@"id"]); on all the nslogs that are depending on the test array

Comment: if anyone figures it out it would be great! I'm off to sleep for a few hours but I look forward to see the replies in the morning. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *array = [dataDictionary valueForKey:@"test"];
for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++){
NSLog(@"%@", [array[i] valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

like that u can get NSLog whatever key you want
for id

```
NSLog(@"%@", [array[i] valueForKey:@"id"]);
```

for lat

```
NSLog(@"%@", [array[i] valueForKey:@"lat"]);
```

and so on.....
Happy coding